# Is it possible to use R Plotly library in R Script Visual of Power BI?

Tags: r, highcharts, plotly, powerbi

Has anyone tried using `Plotly` or `Highchart` in R Script Visual of Power BI,

when I try this in R script editor and Run:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
x <- 1:5
y <- c(1, 3, 2, 3, 1)
plot_ly(x = dataset$period, y = dataset$mean, name = "spline", line = list(shape = "spline"))
```

Error Message:

> No image was created. The R code did not result in creation of any visuals. Make sure your R script results in a plot to the R default device.

But runs perfectly on my R desktop. Any thought?

Comment: as of March 6, 2017 plot_ly is supported in Power BI: [Power BI Announcement](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-r-visuals/). There has been issues with getting plot_ly to run after the release [Power BI Fourm](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Plot-ly-is-now-3-2017-on-the-list-for-R-packages-in-Power-BI-I/m-p/141660#M61046).

Comment: @Dave D. Did my suggestion solve your problem?

Answer (score 12):

For newer versions of PowerBI, it's also possible to produce `Plotly` charts using `R` and  `ggplot` as **`custom PowerBI visualizations`**. With the approach described below, you can produce a density plot from a PowerBI table like this:

[image]

---

**Resources:**

My suggested solution uses **`nodejs`** that can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/en/). That, as well as the main parts of my suggestion builds on [this excellent blogpost](http://radacad.com/interactive-map-using-r-and-power-bi-create-custom-visual-part-1) that only has some few shortcomings when it comes to the details about using and updating **`custom PowerBI Visualizations`**. I *could* just refer to that link and point out the things I did differently, but for the sake of clarity and completeness, I've done the whole thing from scratch.

---

**Part 1 - Download and install node.js**

---

**1.1:** Link: https://nodejs.org/en/

**1.2:** Restart your computer, launch a command prompt, and run this:

```
npm install -g powerbi-visuals-tools
```

**1.3:** Check that your installation is successful by running the following in your command prompt:

**Input:**

```
pbiviz
```

**Output:**

[image]

---

**Part 2: Make a PowerBI custom visual**

---

**2.1:** Create a folder to contain your custom visualizations.

I'm using a command prompt to do this

```
# from the C:\ directory:
md pbiCustomR
cd pbiCustomR
```

In that folder, run the following command:

```
pbiviz new pbiDensity -t rhtml
```

This will create a new visual and install some required packages. You can change `pbiDensity` to whatever your want.

**2.2:** Navigate to the folder `C:\pbiCustomR\pbiDensity` and take a closer look at the contents.

There's a lot of stuff there, but we are only going to focus on the file `script.R` as well as the file `pbiDensity.pbiviz` (located in the subfolder `dist`). `script.R` is a template that sets up your R script. We're going to edit that later. `pbiDensity.pbiviz` is a PowerBI custom visualization that you'll import in Power BI later too.

**2.3:** Open the file `C:\pbiCustomR\pbiDensity\script.R` to see this (I highly recommend RStudio):

```
source('./r_files/flatten_HTML.r')

############### Library Declarations ###############
libraryRequireInstall("ggplot2");
libraryRequireInstall("plotly")
####################################################

################### Actual code ####################
g = qplot(`Petal.Length`, data = iris,fill = `Species`, main = Sys.time());
####################################################

############# Create and save widget ###############
p = ggplotly(g);
internalSaveWidget(p, 'out.html');
####################################################
```

The snippet above uses a dataset from the `Iris` dataset, but we're going to make use of data available in a PowerBI file by adding this line:

```
df <- data.frame(X = Values$Data)
```

That line builds a dataframe from an existing column i PowerBI file that we're going to to name `Data`. But first, go ahead and change the complete snippet above to:

```
source('./r_files/flatten_HTML.r')

############### Library Declarations ###############
libraryRequireInstall("ggplot2");
libraryRequireInstall("plotly")
####################################################

################### Actual code ####################
df <- data.frame(X = Values$Data)

# Build basic ggplot
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = X))

# Add density plot
g = g + geom_density(colour = 'blue')

############# Create and save widget ###############
p = ggplotly(g);
internalSaveWidget(p, 'out.html');
####################################################
```

---

**2.4:** Finish your custom visualization.

---

In the folder `C:\pbiCustomR\pbiDensity`, run the following command using the command prompt:

```
pbiviz package
```

This will trigger this output:

[image]

And that's it when it comes to the more advanced stuff. The rest is easy!

---

**Part 3 - Make some random data in PowerBI using R**

---

**3.1** Under the `Home` tab, click `Edit Queries` to open the `Power Query Editor`.

**3.2** Click `Enter Data`, and ***only*** click `OK`.

**3.3** Select `Transform > Run R Script` and insert the following snippet:

```
set.seed(123)
output <- data.frame(rnorm(100, mean=100, sd=10))
```

This will produce a new step under `Query Settings` called `"output"`, as well as a table with random numbers with not the best column name in the world.

**3.4** Change the name of the step under `Applied Steps` to `tblRandom`, and the name of the column to `SampleData` so you'll end up with this:

[image]

**3.5** Select `Home > Close&Apply` to get back to PowerBI Desktop.

---

**Part 4 - Import and use your custom visualization

---

**4.1** Under `Visualizations`, click the icon with the three dots and select `Import from file`:

[image]

**4.1** Navigate to `C:\pbiCustomR\pbiDensity\dist`, select `pbiDensity.pbiviz`, click `OK` and a new icon should appear under `Visualizations`:

[image]

**`And this is important`:** In order for your visualization to work, the name of your column ***has*** to match the reference in your R script. And in our case, they don't (just to make a point out of it). So change the name column `SampleData` to `Data`.

**4.2** Click your new icon to insert a visualization placeholder, and drag your `Data` column to it:

[image]

And there you go:

[image]

Now you have the full flexibility of the `plotly` toolbar at your disposal:

[image]

---

**Part 5 - Edit R script, update and reimport custom visualization**

---

**5.1** Edit your script in RStudio and save it without changing the filename

**5.2** Navigate to your custom folder and run `pbiviz package`

**5.3** Delete your existing custom visual in PowerBI and import it again

Comment: I'm working on this now, but when I write this line in the cmd prompt:
pbiviz new pbiDensity -t html

I get this error message:
 info   Creating new visual
 error  Unable to create visual. Error: Invalid template

Any help/advice on fixing this would be great.

Comment: Just a point, running 'pbiviz new ANYNAME -t html" throw me an error:  "error  Unable to create visual. Error: Invalid template", so I have to change it to "pbiviz new ANYNAME -t rhtml"

Comment: @mohsenhs That's a valuable piece of information! Thanks!

Comment: thanks @vestland, hope helps others as the answer helped me. The answer to this question is a nice short tutorial and it worth keeping up to date:)

Comment: @mohsenhs Glad to hear it's still valuable to some!

Comment: Just another point based on , https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Custom-Visuals-Development/Cannot-import-multiple-r-script-sources-in-RHTML-visual/td-p/765719, I got  TS2741: Property 'forEach' is missing in type 'HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLHeadElement>' but required in type 'NodeListOf<HTMLHeadElement>'. so I changed NodeListOf by HTMLCollectionOf type in /src/visual.ts . Just an issue regarding an update

Comment: Thanks @vestland - Awesome post!

One point to highlight is that the name of the dataset passed by the Power BI app to the R script is "Values", as opposed to "dataset" for straight R script visuals in Power BI.  My prototype PBI app used an R script visual, which I then modified into a plotly object.  The simple modification was this line:

dataset <- Values

Then
dataset %>%
...

Comment: Just a note - it appears that there is an issue with the powerbi-visuals-tools npm package (currently 5.1.1) that prevents the visual from being displayed. Based on help forum comments, it appears version 4.05 was the last functioning package at this time. To install version 4.05, use this: npm install -g powerbi-visuals-tools

  Here's the forum post that describes this issue.

https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Developer/Issue-with-R-plotly-in-pbiviz-versions-4-0-6/m-p/2940046

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that right now Power BI only supports render charts created by R visualization component as PNG.

Try the following:

```
p <- plot_ly(x = dataset$period, y = dataset$mean, name = "spline", line = list(shape = "spline"))
plotly_IMAGE(p, format = "png", out_file = "out.png")
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

pbiviz new pbiDensity -t html

for

pbiviz new pbiDensity -t rhtml