# Plotly in R Power BI

Tags: sql-server, r, powerbi

How I can create interactive R plots in Power BI (for example Plotly)? Below code doesn't return any error, but also doesn't show chart:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

z = ggplot(data = dataset) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = Console, y = Search))
ggplotly(z)
```

Data source:

```
source <- "https://cdn.rawgit.com/BlueGranite/Microsoft-R-Resources/master/power-bi/gameconsole.csv"  
game.console <- read.csv(source, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: `plotly` is not available in Power BI. See http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Is-it-possible-to-use-R-charts-that-use-the-plotly-library-in/td-p/94895

Answer (score 4):

According to [this question in Power BI's Community forums](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Documentation-needed-for-Plotly-in-Powerbi/td-p/201651)

> Plotly lib is supported as part of HTML support for R powered Custom
> Visuals only, not R Visuals in general currently.
>
> Plotly can only be used if it produces an IMAGE\PNG for R visuals in
> PBI. Not HTML.
>
> For Custom Visuals we have an upcoming feature which will also enable R-based custom visuals to render as htmls.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Jared, Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please dont forget to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that right now Power BI only supports render charts created by R visualization component as PNG.

Try the following:

```
p <- plot_ly(x = dataset$period, y = dataset$mean, name = "spline", line = list(shape = "spline"))
plotly_IMAGE(p, format = "png", out_file = "out.png")
```

But the problem with this is that, though rendered by plotly, the visualizations will not be interactive since its just a PNG image.

If you want to create interactive visualizations using plotly. The only way you can do is to create a custom Power BI visualization and import it to your report. See [this](http://radacad.com/interactive-charts-using-r-and-power-bi-create-custom-visual-part-2) post for a good introduction.

Answer (score 0):

PowerBI only supports charts rendered as PNG while plotly format is in HTML. You can try to save the chart as PNG then print it in the R console inside PowerBI.
You first have to register a plotly account [here](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/Auth/login/#/).

After registration, on the top right corner arrow next to your account name and click on Settings -> API keys. You will be able to generate API key. Copy and paste your username and API key using this code.

```
Sys.setenv("plotly_username"="....")
Sys.setenv("plotly_api_key"=".....")
```

Then add this code in to turn the plot into png format and print it out.

```
fig <- plot_ly(x = dataset$Console, y = dataset$Search)
Png <- plotly_IMAGE(fig, out_file = "plotly-test-image.png")
print(Png)
```

As mentioned in another answer, this plot won't be interactive as plot in PowerBI. To create an interactive plot in PowerBI, you have to create a custom visual. Follow an R custom visual example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39368729/is-it-possible-to-use-r-plotly-library-in-r-script-visual-of-power-bi) or radacad example [here](https://radacad.com/create-custom-visual-with-r-and-json-part-4).