# Custom visual in Power BI using Python

Tags: python, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am trying to replicate this for Python, but cannot find any answer:

[Is it possible to use R Plotly library in R Script Visual of Power BI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39368729/is-it-possible-to-use-r-plotly-library-in-r-script-visual-of-power-bi)

or :

https://radacad.com/interactive-map-using-r-and-power-bi-create-custom-visual-part-1

Just  to be a little more specific:
How can I change the offered solution to work with script.py rather than  script.R

Any help is highly appreciated.

I have found that in this folder there is a file called capabilities.json, so I assume this is one part of the solution:

```
  "script": {
      "scriptProviderDefault": "R", ###I guess this needs to be changed to Py
      "scriptOutputType": "html",
      "source": {
        "objectName": "rcv_script",# not sure about this
        "propertyName": "source"
      },
      "provider": {
        "objectName": "rcv_script",# not sure about this
        "propertyName": "provider"
      }
    }
```

And also after removing referencing dependecies.json in this project, and after building and importing this to Power BI, I got this error

```
 Error Message:
 An exception of type System.ArgumentException occured.

 Stack Trace:
 System.ArgumentException: The supplied rendering engine is not supported
 at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ExecuteSemanticQueryFlow.TransformDat aShapeResult(QueryCommand transformCommand, SemanticQueryDataShapeCommand command, Stream dataShapeResultStream, QueryBindingDescriptor& bindingDescriptor)
 at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ExecuteSemanticQueryFlow.ExecuteDataQuery(IQueryResultDataWriter queryResultDataWriter, EngineDataModel engineDataModel, DataQuery query, Int32 queryId, ServiceErrorStatusCode& serviceErrorStatusCode, CancellationToken cancelToken)
 at Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreHost.SemanticQuery.ExecuteSemanticQueryFlow.ProcessAndWriteSemanticQueryCommands(IQueryResultsWriter queryResultsWriter, IList`1 queries, HashSet`1 pendingQueriesToCancel, EngineDataModel engineDataModel)
```

Comment: What part are you stuck on?

Comment: part 2.2. of the stackoverflow answer. i.e. "script.R is a template that sets up your R script. We're going to edit that later". So if I put script.py there, not sure how the pbivis understands to look for script.py rather than script.R after running this command "pbiviz package"

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not, had to do it in R

Comment: [These R packages are supported in Power BI.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-r-packages-support) And [these Python libraries are supported.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-python-packages-support) Plotly is not on that list, so yes, you'll have to do it in R.