# Power BI: include an htmlwidget other than a plotly graphic

Tags: r, powerbi, htmlwidgets

Following [this amazing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55022829/1100107) and [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/interactive-power-bi-custom-visuals-with-r-a6a4ac998710), I have been able to include an interactive `ggplotly` in Power BI:

[image]

I'm wondering whether it is possible to include other ***htmlwidgets***. I tried with ***DT*** and ***rAmCharts4*** but I got only an empty plot, without error notification. Would you have an example of another ***htmlwidget*** included in Power BI?

---

## EDIT

I finally managed with ***DT***. And with ***highcharter***.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I know manage, I answer my own question. Here is an example. First, install `pbiviz` as explained in the links given in my question.

- create a working directory: `mkdir pbivizWorkplace` and go into: `cd pbivizWorkplace`
- inititalize a new visual: `pbiviz new Ggiraph -t rhtml`
- in the created folder `Ggiraph`, edit ***pbiviz.json***; you have to write something for `description` (what you want), `supportUrl` (e.g. `https://www.example.com`), and `name` and `email`
- edit `script.r`, e.g.:

---

```
source('./r_files/flatten_HTML.r')

############### Library Declarations ###############
libraryRequireInstall("ggplot2");
libraryRequireInstall("ggiraph")
####################################################

################### Actual code ####################
data <- Values # we will use 'mtcars' as 'Values'
data$carname <- row.names(data)
gg_point <- ggplot(data = data) +
  geom_point_interactive(aes(x = wt, y = qsec, color = disp,
                             tooltip = carname, data_id = carname)) + 
  theme_minimal()
####################################################

############# Create and save widget ###############
p <- girafe(ggobj = gg_point)
internalSaveWidget(p, 'out.html');
####################################################

################ Reduce paddings ###################
ReadFullFileReplaceString('out.html', 'out.html', ',"padding":[0-9]*,', ',"padding":0,')
####################################################
```

The data imported in Power BI corresponds to `Values` in the script.

Since we want to use `mtcars` as data, we save it as an Excel file, but before that, we add a column with the row names, because we will use the row names as tooltips:

mtcars$carname <- rownames(mtcars)
openxlsx::write.xlsx(mtcars, "mtcars.xlsx")

- Go to the folder ***pbivizWorkplace/Ggiraph*** and run `pbiviz package`
- Open Power BI, import ***mtcars.xlsx***, select and load the sheet
- In the 'Visualizations' panel, click the three dots, the 'import a visual from a file', and select the ***pbiviz*** file in ***pbivizWorkplace/Ggiraph/dist***
- a new icon (showing some tools) appears at the bottom in the 'Visualizations' panel, click it
- in the 'Fields' panel, select the columns used for the plot, here `wt`, `qsec`,  `disp` and `carname`
- you get the interactive graphic in Power BI:

[image]