# Why is my R visual not displaying in Power BI?

Tags: r, powerbi

On my personal device I have R and RStudio installed. I then opened Power BI Desktop and enabled R scripting (so that I could embed an R visual into the report). Power BI automatically detected that I have R installed.

[image]

I then typed the following R code into my R visual in Power BI:

```
library(plotly)

Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
SF_Zoo <- c(20, 14, 23)
LA_Zoo <- c(12, 18, 29)
data <- data.frame(Animals, SF_Zoo, LA_Zoo)

fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~Animals, y = ~SF_Zoo, type = 'bar', name = 'SF Zoo')
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~LA_Zoo, name = 'LA Zoo')
fig <- fig %>% layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'group')

fig
```

But it keeps saying 'Can't display this visual':

[image]

Comment: And when you click “Display details”?

Comment: It reads: 

Error Message:
No image was created. The R code didn't result in creation of any visuals. Make sure your R script results in a plot to the R default device.

Comment: "Make sure your R script results in a plot to the R default device" sounds like it's not made to work with plotly, which outputs to the viewer.

Comment: see the link given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68668525/interactive-r-plotly-graphic-in-power-bi-with-pbiviz

Comment: Here for a short tuto: <https://stackoverflow.com/a/68673071/1100107>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of R supported by power bi visuals in 3.4.4 - you are trying to create your visual on 4.2.1.